# Tabwidget not visible under toolbar/navbar in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have constructed a `TabHost` inside my navigation drawer. That means I've created 3 `Fragment` with `xml` files each: `ExhibitorFragment`, `TabInternationalFragment`, and `TabLocalFragment`. Now the problem is, I can't see my tabwidget under the `Toolbar` even though it displays design `xml` in either two of the fragments.

**below is my code for ExhibitorFragment.java:**

```
public class ExhibitorFragment extends Fragment{


public ExhibitorFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_exhibitor);

    Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
    arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Frag Tab1"),
            TabInternationalFragment.class, arg1);

    Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
    arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Frag Tab2"),
            TabLocalFragment.class, arg2);


    return mTabHost;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mTabHost = null;
}

}
```

**fragment_exhibitor.xml :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.guitarista.citem.Example">

    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/International"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Local"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

The `TabInternationalFragment` and `TabLocalFragment` are set to default when created same as their respected `xml` (fragment_tab_international, fragment_tab_local).

Answer (score 0):

**Your Java Code Is correct Try Changing the XML file to this format**

```
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: I've got rendering problems. Is it normal?

Comment: yep,It's perfectly normal....The Layout will be visible only in the runtime

Comment: May be u need to do some changes in the java file.

Comment: Well maybe. But even if I change the java file, the app will not respond otherwise. So this is the only code that I've got working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Usr this code

```
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" 
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/International"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Local"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Whats the difference in this one? I cant seem to see.

Comment: android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab2"),
            tab1.class,null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("tab2"), tab2.class, null);
```

Comment: still no luck brother. may its hard to translate some of the codes, because Im implementing these in fragments instead of the MainActivity itself.

Comment: Compile with this and try it out
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'

Comment: You mean dependencies? Ill see what I can do

Comment: Its my default dependencies. The java might be the problem

Comment: can't get what u are saying

Comment: can u share the log

Comment: My event log is clean. The problem is when I debug the app, it becomes not responsive "Unfortunately, asdasd has Stopped"

Comment: android.R.id.tabhost must be mentioned.

Comment: usually they make error when u replace it with R.id.tabhost insted of android.R.id.tabhost

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this tutorial [Android Tabs in Fragments](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/). Though this one is likely similar to Pager Sliding tab strip. Take Note that you still need to implement fragment codes for this to work.